# no margin double line list item

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I have this list with a couple of items. I want a top margin of 10px between Li's, this is all fine, unless the LI has two lines, then you get the below problem: the li doesn't seem to take into account the second line when deciding its margin. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image: styled components]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of code. Add the rendered HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You might have some other code overwriting this part?
I don't seem to be able to reproduce your issue as below:

```css
li {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Paragraph<br>Paragraph</li>
  <li>Paragraph Paragraph</li>
  <li>Paragraph<br>Paragraph</li>
  <li>Paragraph Paragraph</li>
  <li>Paragraph<br>Paragraph</li>
</ul>
```